# Solve PDE $y^2(x−y)p+ x^2(y − x)q =z(x^2 + y^2)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$y^2(x−y)p+ x^2(y − x)q =z(x^2 + y^2)$

this is linear PDE and can be written in form of Lagrange's auxiliary equation.

$\frac{dx}{y^2(x−y)} = \frac{dy}{x^2(y − x)} = \frac{dz}{(x^2 + y^2)}$

first to fraction can be solved by ode

$x^2dx = -y^2dy$

$x^3+y^3 = C_1$

I got one solution by solving first two fractions of dx and dy.
Now how to solve further?
I can't find multipliers.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake when writing Lagrange's auxiliary equations. The last term should be
$$
\frac{dz}{z(x^2+y^2)}. \tag{1}
$$
To find a second integral, we can combine the first two terms as
$$
\frac{dx}{y^2(x−y)} = \frac{dy}{x^2(y − x)}=\frac{dx-dy}{(x-y)(y^2+x^2)}. \tag{2}
$$
Equating $(1)$ to $(2)$ we obtain
$$
\frac{dz}{z(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{d(x-y)}{(x-y)(x^2+y^2)}\implies \frac{dz}{z}=\frac{d(x-y)}{x-y}\implies z=C_2(x-y). \tag{3}
$$
Combining $(3)$ with the first integral $x^3+y^3=C_1$, we can write the general solution to the PDE as
$$
z(x,y)=(x-y)f(x^3+y^3), \tag{4}
$$
where $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

Comment: Thank you so much